# Django, Python: Best way to parse a CSV and convert to Django model instances

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a page where a user uploads a CSV file. That bit works.

I can read the CSV and turn it into lists. It takes a fair bit of time for something I thought should be faster (about 7 seconds to parse through and convert it to lists, for a 17mb CSV file).

I'm wondering now though, what would be the best approach to doing this? The code I have so far is very convoluted (written a long time ago by a CS graduate colleague that has since left) and I think I want to rewrite it as it's too slow.

I haven't worked with CSVs before. Right now this is what I have:

```
import codecs
import csv
import sys

def read_csv_file(self, file_path):
    is_file = False
    while not is_file:
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            is_file = True
    result_data = []

    csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)

    csv_reader = csv.reader(codecs.open(file_path, 'rU', 'utf-8'), delimiter=',')

    for row in csv_reader:
        result_data.append(row)

    return result_data
```

Is turning a CSV into lists (that I can then perhaps zip?) the best way to go about it?

Ultimately, the goal is to create DB objects (in a loop perhaps?) that would be something like looping through each list, using an index to create objects, appending those objects to an object list and then doing a bulk_create:

```
object_instance_list.append(My_Object.objects.get_or_create(property=csv_property[some_index], etc etc)[0])
My_Object.bulk_create(object_instance_list)
```

Would that be efficient?

Should I be working with dicts instead?

Is there a built in method that would allow this for either Python's CSV or a bit of Django functionality that already does it?

Basically, since I'm not that experience, and this is my first time working with CSVs, I would like to get it right(ish) from the beginning.

I would appreciate any help in this regard, so I can learn the proper way to handle this. Thanks!

Comment: You better would use the dictionary mode I guess.

Comment: How do you define **"best"**? If your **"best"** is maximum speed than the best solution will be: bypass django and import records into db-table directly from csv.

Comment: **"Best"** would be speed and efficiency, within Django parameters. The upload of the CSV is already taken care of, as well as selecting the right file and sending a request to process it to my webserver. The processing is where I stop. After that ideally I would need a list of objects I can send back to a Django bulk_create constructor. It's mainly the in-between I don't know how to tackle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this is untested, but conceptually you should be able to get the idea. The trick is to take advantage of using `**kwargs`.

```
import csv

def read_csv():
    """Read the csv into dictionaries, transform the keys necessary
    and return a list of cleaned-up dictionaries.
    """
    with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        return [map_rows_to_fields(row) for row in reader]

def map_rows_to_fields(row):
    """Here for each dictionary you want to transform the dictionary
    in order to map the keys of the dict to match the names of the
    fields on the model you want to create so we can pass it in as
    `**kwargs`. This would be an opportunity to use a nice dictionary
    comprehension.
    """
    csv_fields_to_model_fields = {
        'csv_field_1': 'model_field_1',
        'csv_field_2': 'model_field_2',
        'csv_field_n': 'model_field_n',
    }
    return {
        csv_fields_to_model_fields[key]: value
        for key, value in row.items()
    } 

def instantiate_models():
    """Finally, we have our data from the csv in dictionaries
    that map values to expected fields on our model constructor,
    then we can just instantiate each of those models from the
    dictionary data using a list comprehension, the result of which
    we pass as the argument to `bulk_create` saving the rows to 
    the database.
    """
    model_data = read_csv()
    MyModel.objects.bulk_create([
        MyModel(**data) for data in model_data
    ])
```

The method `bulk_create` does have a few caveats though so make sure it's ok to use it in your case.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

If you can't use `bulk_create` then just make the models in a loop.

```
for data in model_data:
    MyModel.objects.create(**data)
```

Comment: Creating through bulk_create is valid in this case. I have a few other cases where I'm doing just that. It also saves a ton of time.

Comment: Good stuff, I'm just covering the edge cases for anyone else who might see the answer.

Comment: Your answer is great. I was mainly interested in seeing whether I should work with lists or dicts, and what was a good approach. Thanks for your help!